# Incremental loading divs causes width of d3 chart to miscalculate

Tags: jquery, css, d3.js

I have a page with a bunch of divs holding d3 graphs that use the below code to auto-scale with the width of the div on load:

```
width = parseInt(d3.select('svg').style('width'), 10)
```

I load the divs incrementally using this function:

```
$('.card').each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay((i + 1) * 100).fadeIn(300);
         });
```

So, in the CSS the divs are set to 'display:none'

On load, the '.card' divs have a width of 300px and the svg graph has a width of 100px. Tried delaying the load of the svgs without success.

Edit: screenshot:
[image]

Comment: When are you running the code to calculate the width? In what way is it "miscalculated"?

Comment: Hey - I added a screenshot. The width is supposed to fit the container (svg has a width of 100% within the card). The code runs under $(document).ready

Comment: The problem seems to be with the 'display:none' line

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the problem is. Why don't you simply set the width of the SVG to 100% to start with?